# Using real time updates from facebook graph api with a client application

Tags: windows, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use Facebook's [Realtime updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) feature with my app.

My app is a client app, but as far as I can tell from the documentation I need to make a HTTP POST request to the `/APP_ID/subscriptions` endpoint which includes a `callback_url` parameter.

Is this callback url necessary?.

As I am working with windows 8 metro style application I cannot define a callback url for the app because this is client-side code.

Comment: nominating for reopen - the question was phrased poorly, but i'm editing it now to make more sense and i think it's a valid question

Answer (score 2):

Without a callback URL how would Facebook contact you to tell you there are new updates?

Short answer, no, there's no way to receive real-time updates without a callback URL